# How about a Review API?

Tags: feature-request

I think it would be fun and interesting to create a Review API.  We could then write algorithms to attempt to moderate posts and see how close we can get to human moderation.  Battle of the bots.  We wouldn't even have to use the responses from these bots right away and maybe they could offer some prizes for bots that exceed expectations.

Comment: They already did this years and years ago with coming up for heuristics for duplicates (at least I think it was duplicates).

Comment: Just to be clear, you're asking for a *read-only* API for reviews, right?  That would be pretty nice.

Comment: @davidism Even one that allows us to send responses would be good, the responses don't have to be acted upon... just tallied somewhere and compared to the human moderation.  Or I guess alternatively, read-only, but an option for lagged only on already moderated items so we can compare the results on our own.

Comment: Anonymous users who click the vote arrows are still counted internally as "feedback", the votes just don't count.  I could understand a review API that worked like that, although I'm not sure the work involved would be worth it.  I'd definitely be worried about counting automated reviews in real time, a lot of potential for abuse or just mistakes there.

Comment: This would certainly make dealing with robo-reviewers that much easier.

Comment: Have you looked at the data in SEDE?  Unless I'm mistaken (and that's certainly a possibility) the data explorer is just importing the public dumps.  I know it's not exactly live data, but with offline data you can do much more complex analysis than you could using the API.